# Ratio of Two Natural Number Squares, Cubes or Higher Power with a Common Factor

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let there be two natural numbers $z$ and $w$ each raised to the same positive whole number power $n$ greater than $1$. Then let $z^n=a r$ and $w^n=a s$, with $a$ being a common natural number factor.

On calculating the $n$'th root of $\frac{z^n}{w^n}$ we have

$$\sqrt[^n]{\frac{z^n}{w^n}}=\sqrt[^n]{\frac{a r}{a s}}=\sqrt[^n]{\frac{ r}{s}}=\frac{ \sqrt[^n]{r} }{\sqrt[^n]{s}}=\frac{z}{w}(= \mathbb{Q})$$

Since $r$ and $s$ are whole numbers; is $a=t^n$, $r=u^n$ and $s=v^n$, where $t$, $u$ and $v$ are all whole numbers as well, the only solution?

If so I am not sure how to prove by contradiction that no other solutions exist, for example where a common irrational factor to $\sqrt[^n]{r}$ and  $\sqrt[^n]{s}$ cancels out, leaving the rational number answer?

Do I have to add the constraint that when $a$ is taken as the common factor, that $r$ and $s$ must be left relatively prime?

Comment: $r$ and $s$ should be relatively prime, otherwise e.g.  $4^2 = 2\times 8$ and $6^2 = 2\times 18$.

Comment: @peterwhy: or another way of putting it, $a$ must be relatively prime to both $r$ and $s$

Comment: @peterwhy: sorry the minimal constraint is that $a$ is relatively prime to either $r$ or $s$, not necessarily both of them.